# Any Call Center conversation log dataset?

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis, knime

I am analyzing several Sentiment Analysis algorithms to classify and prioritize call center calls.
I have been trying to look for this type of data on the web, but found nothing.

Ideally I would like to have several two-way conversations, preferably regarding baking or insurance industry.

The idea is to process this data in order to see if the customer is hangry, and needs a fast reply, or if he hasn't much urgency.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched through Kaggle's datesets yet? They have some call center data on there but I'm not sure any of its relevant to what you are looking for. The closest I saw was 'insurance cold calls' but that's still not quite it for your needs.